# centre image and keep navigation visible

Tags: html, css

The image should resize (up to max) but I need the navigation div to always be visible. At the moment it is being hidden when I resize the browser. Ideally it should move up with the image.

here is the code I have already. Also, is there a way of placing the image in the centre of the screen.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>        
</head>

    <body style="margin:0;padding:0; height:100%">
            <div style=" border:solid 1px green; ">           
                <img style="max-height:400px; height:100%;" src="../Images/img-02.jpg" />    
            </div>      
            <div style="border:solid 1px red;height:30px;position: relative;">navigation</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: what do you mean "hidden"? i tried in few browsers and it's never covered by img. As for centre - `text-align: center;` is your friend: `<div style=" border:solid 1px green; text-align: center;">           
                <img style="max-height:400px; height:100%;" src="file2.gif" />    
            </div>`

Comment: hi - i mean the nav bar should always be visible when resizing the browser to a smaller size. In chrome the nav bar was not showing when I resized the browser to a smaller size.

Comment: do you mean vertical scroll bar appears and nav bar goes outside of browsers visible area?

Comment: yes - I have added some images

Comment: that's because your img is 100% height - meaning it will stretch 100% of visible browser's area. BTW `max-height:400px;` will not work in IE - use css: `height: expression( this.scrollHeight > 399 ? "400px" : "auto" );`

Comment: I need the image to resize so how do I do this without setting the image size to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

This can be rectified using some scripting

```
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    var hVal = window.innerHeight;
    if(hVal>434){
        document.getElementById("test").height = 400;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("test").height = hVal-34;
    }
}
window.onresize = function(){
    var hVal = window.innerHeight;
    if(hVal>434){
        document.getElementById("test").height = 400;
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("test").height = hVal-34;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0; height:100%">
<div style=" border:solid 1px green; ">           
            <img id="test" src="../Images/img-02.jpg" />    
</div>      
<div style="border:solid 1px red;height:30px;position: relative;">navigation</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope it works...!

Comment: note that 434 = 400(required width of the image) + 2(top and bottom border width of the image div) + 2(top and bottom border width of the navigation div) + 30(height of the navigation div)